# Javascript do not reload parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm working on a project. This includes a div which I've loaded in with jQuerys' `.load()`. Now I want to refresh that every 10 seconds. So in the loaded page, I've done the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload(1);
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

But for some reason, this reloads not only the frame, but also the parent. I've also tried to reload the div which I'm loading into with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#radiostatusInner").load("/public/assets/scripts/radiostatus.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#radiostatusInner").load('/public/assets/scripts/radiostatus.php');
        }, 10000);
        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

But this gives me the same result...

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You do realize that location.reload refreshes the whole document yes?

Comment: what frame are you talking about? There is no frame shown in question

Comment: `$(...).load(...)` doesn't create an iframe, so you are reloading the whole page.  If it were an iframe, it would work (see http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/w4L0v684/)

Answer (score 1):

`location.reload()` reloads the parent window, so unless your content is in an iframe (and you're targeting that iframe) that will always refresh the entire page.

The second snippet should work (remove the first snippet if it's still there), but it's not ideal. Your timer isn't aware of when the AJAX request will return.

Something like this would be better:

```
(function getRadioStatusInner() {
    $("#radiostatusInner").load("/public/assets/scripts/radiostatus.php", function() {
        setTimeout(getRadioStatusInner, 10000);
    });
}());
```

Comment: For some reason, even with some editting, I dont see anything... It just gives me an empty div.

Comment: Are you familiar with Chrome's (or any browser really) dev tools?  Take a look under the Network tab to see if the calls are being made and what the response is.  I ran the code I sent you through CodePen using Google.com and verified that it made the calls every 10 seconds after a response was returned.

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet of code you've shown should work as you need, but you should remove the first snippet from the loaded page, because it will make the entire page reload once it gets loaded and appended to the DOM.

Only use the second snippet in your page and everything should work as expeced.

Comment: I am only using the second snippet, but for some reason its still the whole page reloading.